# Trying to filter a CSV file with multiple variables using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("adult.data.csv")

print("data shape: "+str(data.shape))
print("number of rows: "+str(data.shape[0]))
print("number of cols: "+str(data.shape[1]))
print(data.columns.values)

datahist = {}
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    k = str(row['age']) + str(row['sex']) + 
str(row['workclass']) + str(row['education']) + 
str(row['marital-status']) + str(row['race'])
    if k in datahist:
        datahist[k] += 1
    else:
        datahist[k] = 1
uniquerows = 0
for key, value in datahist.items():
    if value == 1:
        uniquerows += 1
print(uniquerows)

for key, value in datahist.items():
    if value == 1: 
        print(key)

df.loc[data['age'] == 58] & df.loc[data['sex'] == Male]
```

I have been trying to get the above code to work.

I have limited experience in coding but it seems like the issue lies with some of the columns being objects. The int64 columns work just fine when it comes to filtering.

Any assistance will be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you mention what you have been trying to achieve and how it failed ?

Comment: and also sample data to make it reproducible.

Comment: Why do you have them both duplicated? for key, value in datahist.items(): Can you used if/else condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[data['age'] == 58] & df.loc[data['sex'] == Male]
```

Firstly you are attemping to use `Male` variable, you probably meant string, i.e. it should be `'Male'`, secondly observe `[` and `]` placement, you are extracting part of DataFrame with `age` equal 58 then extracting part of DataFrame with `sex` equal `Male` and then try to use bitwise and. You should probably use `&` with conditions rather than pieces of DataFrame that is

```
df.loc[(data['age'] == 58) & (data['sex'] == 'Male')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The int64 columns work just fine because you've specified the condition correctly as:

`data['age'] == 58`

However, the object column condition `data['sex'] == Male` should be specified as a string:

`data['sex'] == 'Male'`

Also, I noticed that you have loaded the dataframe `df = pd.read_csv("adult.data.csv")`. Do you mean this instead?

`data = pd.read_csv("adult.data.csv")`

The query at the end includes 2 conditions, and should be enclosed in brackets within the square brackets `[  ]` filter. If the dataframe name is `data` (instead of `df`), it should be:

```
data.loc[ (data['age'] == 58]) & (data['sex'] == Male) ]
```

Comment: hi @CodingNoob  is my suggestion able to answer your question?